# How to specify value in model relation keys?

Tags: yii2

I have tables `user` and `profile`, 
one user has max one profile, 
and is specified by **user_id** and **table name** in profile.
I do not use foreign keys there.

The reason I do it this way, is because I have other tables like `company` which also uses table `profile`, so reference is specified by **relation_id = primary key of related table** and **relation = table name**

```
profile 
    relation_id
    relation
```

What I want to achieve is to set model relation to be equal to string user, so not to use key there, but to use value instead.

**User.php**

```
public function getProfile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::className(),
        ['relation_id' => 'user_id', 'relation' => User::tableName()]);
}
```

**Error** I get:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user.user' in 'on clause'
The SQL being executed was:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user_login`
LEFT JOIN `user` ON `user_login`.`user_id` = `user`.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN `profile` ON `user`.`user_id` = `profile`.`relation_id`
    AND `user`.`user` = `profile`.`relation`
```

It is for generating GridView so sql fails on count first, but error would be the same for `select *`

**SQL I want to achieve**:

```
SELECT * FROM `user_login`
LEFT JOIN `user` ON `user_login`.`user_id` = `user`.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN `profile` ON `user`.`user_id` = `profile`.`relation_id`
    AND `profile`.`relation` = 'user'
```

So the question is, How to specify value in model relation keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your User  has a relation  hasOne with profile  you  should use only

```
public function getProfile()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Profile::className(),
    ['relation_id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

and if you need  a on condition use

```
  public function getProfile()
  {
     return $this->hasOne(Profile::className(),
      ['relation_id' => 'user_id'])->andOnCondition(['relation' => User::tableName()]);

  }
```

Comment: But I use table `profile` for other tables like `company` etc.

Comment: I added SQL I want to achieve, please check now

Comment: I have update the answer  hope is what you are looking for